# Add hanging indent to CKEditor on web page

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, indentation, rich-text-editor

I am working on a project that allows the user to edit a short document on a web page. I use CKEditor 4.5.1 on my web page. All formatting work fine except that the stock CKEditor doesn't have hanging indent (it has indent and outdent). I have been searching ways to add this function with a button on the toolbar. However, I can't find examples showing how to let CKEditor know the paragraph that needs hanging indent. I know the html code to do that. Can somebody suggest how to do this or show me where I can get relevant reference? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's hanging indent? what that HTML code?

Comment: Hanging indent means the first line of the paragraph starts at the first position while the rest of the lines of the paragraph are indented. The Html code is: <p  style="margin-left:50px;text-indent:-50px;">  <br/>Now I can add a button to the toolbar. But how to make CKEditor to recognize the paragraph my cursor is on, therefore I can insert the Html code to the paragraph is my question.

Comment: I managed to create a plugin which copies the selected text, deletes the selected text in the CKEditor, then use the editor.insertHtml() method to insert the text with the html format code into the editor. For example: editor.insertHtml("<div style='margin-left:50px; text-indent:-50px;'>"  + selectedtext + "</div>"). It works well on FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: However, it doesn't work the same way on IE. I figured out it is because when selecting the text in IE (hightlight with mouse), it behaves differently. IE doesn't include the html tags, such as <p>, in the text. Therefore, when the insertHtml() method is executed, the <div style... formatting code is not inserted. Probably it is filtered out by CKEditor. But, if I select the text from one line below, the tags are included, then the formatting code works. But, I can't expect the users to select text in this way. They will only see what is highlighted onscreen.

Comment: Now, my question is how to make CKEditor to include the start and end tags when I select the text. I read the documentation about the range and nodes, but they don't show the methods to do such a job. Does anyone out there have an idea?